# Validação de CheckBox e RadioButton

Tags: java, android

Como validar e retornar uma mensagem caso não seja selecionado os componentes CheckBox e RadioButton em uma aplicação ?  JAVA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tanto no `CheckBox` quanto no `RadioButton` existe um método que pode ser utilizado para fazer este teste, o `isSelected()` que retorna `true` caso seu componente esteja selecionado.

Desta forma você pode utiliza-lo para mostrar sua mensagem, basta que você faça a negação desse teste antes.

```
 if (!seuCheckBox.isSelected()) {
      System.out.println("checkbox não foi selecionado");
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Checkbox não foi Selecionado");
 }
```

No **android** esse mesmo método tem o nome de `isChecked`

```
if (!seuCheckBox.isChecked()) {
  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "checkbox não selecionado",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```